# Jmeter Xslt Test Report "Fatal Error! Content is not allowed in prolog."

Tags: xslt, ant, jmeter

I have been update my jmeter from 2.9 to 2.13. I usually use ant build and xslt to generate html report. Here is my ant xml script :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ballot.xsl"?> 


<project default="all">
  <!-- Define an environment variable pointing to JMETER folder or change this -->
  <property environment="env"/>
 <!-- <property name="jmeter-home" location="${env.JMETER_DIR}"/>-->
 <property name="jmeter-home" location="C:\apache-jmeter-2.13"/>

  <!-- ant-jmeter.jar comes with jmeter, be sure this is the release you have -->
  <path id="ant.jmeter.classpath">
    <pathelement
       location="${jmeter-home}/extras/ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar" />
  </path>
  <taskdef
    name="jmeter"
    classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"
    classpathref="ant.jmeter.classpath" />
  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="results2"/>
    <delete file="jmeter.log"/>
    <mkdir dir="results2/jtl"/>
    <mkdir dir="results2/html"/>
  </target>
  <target name="test" depends="clean">
    <jmeter
       jmeterhome="${jmeter-home}"
       resultlogdir="results2/jtl">
      <testplans dir="IAM_jmeter" includes="*.jmx"/>
    </jmeter>
  </target>
  <!-- This is not needed for the plugin, but it produces a nice html report
       which can be saved usin hudson's archive artifact feature -->
  <target name="report" depends="test">
    <xslt
       basedir="results2/jtl"
       destdir="results2/html"
       includes="*.jtl"
       style="${jmeter-home}/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"/>
  </target>

  <target name="all" depends="test, report"/>
</project>
```

It worked with jmeter 2.9. But when I update to jmeter 2.13, it genereate an error. Here is the error message :

```
[xslt] Transforming into C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\workspace\IAM-JmeterTest-Rest\results2\html
     [xslt] Processing C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\workspace\IAM-JmeterTest-Rest\results2\jtl\IAM_Jmeter.jtl to C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\workspace\IAM-JmeterTest-Rest\results2\html\IAM_Jmeter.html
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl
     [xslt] C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\workspace\IAM-JmeterTest-Rest\results2\jtl\IAM_Jmeter.jtl:1:1: Fatal Error! Content is not allowed in prolog.
     [xslt] Failed to process null
```

Any idea why?
Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that this is due to CSV format of your .jtl file, and for successful XSLT transformation it needs to be XML.

You need to "tell" JMeter to store its results in XML format. To do so add the following line to "test" target:

```
<property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
```

So the whole target would look as:

```
<target name="test" depends="clean">
    <jmeter
            jmeterhome="${jmeter-home}"
            resultlogdir="results2/jtl">
        <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
        <testplans dir="IAM_jmeter" includes="*.jmx"/>
    </jmeter>
</target>
```

Another option is adding the following line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your ${jmeter-home}

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter Properties and ways of setting and overriding them.